# Problem setting up Google Maps API Billing Acount

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-maps-api-3

I hope you are all very well. I'm developing a web platform for an assignment and I need to use the **Maps JavaScript API**. As you know, you are required to provide a credit card number to set up your **billing account**, unfortunately I'm from **Venezuela** and credit cards are not something that you can see every day, first I tried using a false credit card number, it didn't work, then I managed to find someone who had a credit card, but it seems like the credit limits in my country are not even high enough for Google to test that the credit card actually works. I've tried sending requests to the API but all of them have been rejected and I haven't been able to find any ways around this problem. It's very embarrassing to ask for this, but if someone could provide me with an API key that works, I'd very more than grateful, **I can pay for using the API Key**, my only problem is that I don't count with a credit card (I could pay with cryptocurrencies if that were an option), and even if I had a credit card, my country is not included in the list of countries that can be chosen when creating a new billing account. Thanks in advance, it's a very important assignment and I really need some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that you can use a PayPal account. For Google Cloud you can prepay an account, maybe you can do the same with Google Maps.

A shared API key will probably get blocked quickly by Google, so do not try to go that route.

Another idea is to join a local Google Developer Group, someone might be able to help you. Also, sometimes developer/educational credits are available. This is worth your time and can help you with contacts as you develop your skills.

[Google Developer Groups](https://developers.google.com/community/gdg)

[Link to the Caracas GDG](https://gdg.community.dev/gdg-cloud-caracas/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'll get in touch with this developer group and see if there's anything they can do to help me, thanks for your time!